# How to disable the zooming by the mousewheel for ZedGraph

Tags: zedgraph

I want to display a non-zoomable [ZedGraph](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/graphics/zedgraph.aspx) control. How do I disable the mousewheel zooming function in ZedGraph?

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to only disable the zoom by mouse wheel feature, you can use:

```
zedGraphControl.IsEnableWheelZoom = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

If `zgc` is your `ZedGraphControl` instance, use:

```
zgc.ZoomButtons = MouseButtons.None;
zgc.ZoomButtons2 = MouseButtons.None;
```

This will disable zooming by selecting area with mouse.

You will also need to set:

```
zgc.ZoomStepFraction = 0;
```

in order to disable zooming using mouse wheel.